# How to run Twinkle sip client on autostart

Tags: startup, autostart, twinkle

I want to make the twinkle client autostart when the computer boot
didn't find how to do this 
this is what I have on the rc.local

```
     GNU nano 2.7.4                 File: /etc/rc.local                            


/home/pi/.twinkle/twinkle 
'exit 0 '
```

but I guess this is not the command or something?

Thanks ,